# Excel VBA - Copy Cell Value, if empty, to another Cell in the same row

Tags: vba, excel

I am a complete new starter to VBAs and would require your help, my data looks like this:

.  A B C D

1 t t t t

2 t t t t

3 .....      t

4 t t t t

5  t t t t

6 .....       t

7  t t t t

The Macro should check, whether there is some information in Column A:A and if it is empty it should delete the value in the same row in column D.

I hope that you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding on your question, try the below code.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
If Range("A" & i) = "" Then
Range("D" & i).ClearContents
End If
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

you actually need no loops and a one liner:

```
Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, 3).ClearContents
```